# wp_verify_nonce not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, nonce

I'm working on an ajax request, I have several ajax requests on my functions.php. And all are working, but this:

On my php I have this:

```
add_action("wp_ajax_fb_points", "get_fb_points");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_fb_points", "get_fb_points");

function get_fb_points(){
    if ( !wp_verify_nonce($_REQUEST['nonce'], 'fb_points_nonce')) {
        exit('No naughty business');
    }
    echo 'yeah';
    die();
}
```

On the footer.php I have this:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
    function(response) {
        if(response == '<?php echo get_facebook_profile('link'); ?>') {
            $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
                data: { action: 'fb_points', challenge : 2, nonce : '<?php echo wp_create_nonce('fb_points_nonce'); ?>' },
                async: false,
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        }
    }
);
```

But I don't know why it isn't working the request response is "No naugty business". Can anyone help me to find out what is wrong?

Comment: Can you posted the `$_REQUEST['nonce']` and `wp_create_nonce('fb_points_nonce')` values?

Comment: Thanks Rilwis, I noticed that the problems was with the `get_current_user_id()`. I don't know why but I changed with `wp_get_current_user()` and it solves de problem.

Comment: @jepser Where is your wp_get_current_user() function in the above? Usually, the nonce verification would be at the top of the script so I'm not sure where you went wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know I just submitted the ticket on track. I was using `get_current_user_id()` and it modifies the wp_create_nonce behavior.

Sinces `wp_create_nonce` uses `wp_get_current_user()` I think there is the problem.

Comment: get_current_user_id is a wrapper for wp_get_current_user.  wp_create_nonce uses the user id as part of the hash so the method of getting the id makes no difference as long as both methods return the same id. I don't see your ticket can you post a link to it.

Comment: Hi Chris, anyway to check "my tickets" I can't find it out in trac. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

When passing data using ajax I prefer to use [check_ajax_referer](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/check_ajax_referer) instead of wp_verify_nonce.

```
B.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
    function(response) {
        if(response == '<?php echo get_facebook_profile('link'); ?>') {
            $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
                data: { action: 'fb_points', challenge : 2, _ajax_nonce : '<?php echo wp_create_nonce('fb_points_nonce'); ?>' },
                async: false,
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        }
    }
);

function get_fb_points(){
    check_ajax_referer( 'fb_points_nonce');
    echo 'yeah';
    die();
}
```

I believe your method is not working because you are using $_REQUEST instead of $_POST.

```
function get_fb_points(){
    $nonce = $_POST['nonce'];
    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'fb_points_nonce')) {
        exit('No naughty business');
    }
    echo 'yeah';
    die();
}
```

Comment: I used wp_create_nonce('add_list') on a page named "Profile" and output this: cccebe67d7 and then in other page output: bc059709c7. As I know the nonces have to be the same. What do you think is the problem?